# custom display of taxonomy list in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using a "Content:All Taxonomy Fields" field in a View.  Works great, but-

Can I change the display of taxonomy field lists without custom code?  The vocabulary has an image field I've added...I'd love to show the image instead of the name when listed.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a Taxonomy based view instead of Content based?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you'd like to add the image associated to a term in your view ?
If so, in the view go to advanced (right sidebar) => Relationships. choose "Content: Taxonomy terms on node", then in "add fiels" you should be able to add any field of your terms, like name, description or image...

To Avoid duplicate output, go to "advanced => Query settings" and check "Distinct".

In case you have duplicate output anyway, you can try this other solution :

Add a content-> Nid field (Exclude from display).

Add a global php field. In output code, write something inspired from that, with your own details.

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT tid, filename FROM `taxonomy_term_data` INNER JOIN `field_data_field_tags` ";
$q.= "ON `taxonomy_term_data`.tid = `field_data_field_tags`.field_tags_tid ";
$q.= "INNER JOIN `field_data_field_img` ON `taxonomy_term_data`.tid = `field_data_field_img`.entity_id";
$q.= "INNER JOIN `file_managed` ON `file_managed`.fid = `field_data_field_img`.field_img_fid ";
$q.= "WHERE `entity_id` = ".$row -> nid;
$m = db_query($q);
while ($s = $m -> fetchObject()) {
  $img = "path_to_img_folder". $s -> filename;
  $tid = $s -> tid;
  echo "<a href='my_absolute_path/taxonomy/term/".$tid."'>".$img."</a>";
}
?>
```

You'll have then all your taxonomy images displayed in the same row. You may use the style settings to wrap the output with some classes. You'll have also to go to "advanced => Query settings" and check "Distinct". Hope it helps.

Comment: I can do that!  The problem I run in to is if I have multiple matching taxonomy terms, I ultimately get duplicate search results.  In order to avoid the dupes, I have to use "Content: All Taxonomy Fields", instead of associating the actual field I want.

Comment: @user23493 I edited the answer about how to avoid duplicate output. Could you confirm it was useful ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work at the moment. (and is documented to not work when multiple taxonomy nodes match).

Comment: Are you using Aggregation?  Thanks!

Comment: You're right, there are some duplicate output. An alternative may be to use a global Php field to display your images. I edited the answer